# Web-based PDF Document editor

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to build a huge project for the Document management , I am trying now to build a PDF files online-editor , to view the PDF files on the browse  with the ability Highlight text , edit it , , add images , notation and comments.
project like this .
http://www.atalasoft.com/ajaxannotations/

I have already built a PDF viewer , I would like to add the features of editing text in the pdf , adding images , text , shapes .
Is there any Javascript that can help me to achieve that , an Open Source project that can help .

All the best .

Comment: Editing text in a PDF requires reflowing it which is very very difficult – I don't know of any PDF tool that would let you edit PDFs in its free version.

Comment: What about adding notations . Or I thought about  another manner of work getting text from the PDF file than importing it to the editor to edit , after that , switch/convert the document to a pdf file. What do you think ?

Comment: What you can do easily to an existing PDF is add / remove pages, and paint over / under the existing content. Using a different format to edit and store the documents, and only generating PDF to display it is also a perfectly good approach.

Comment: Do you have any idea about any framwork or free lab that can help me to build it .

Comment: Not for PHP, no. Most of the PDF-to-whatever converters I could find aren't free.

Comment: what about ASP.Net , AJAx , Javascript , Any further suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.fpdf.org. I haven't tried it myself, but it seems OK.

Comment: FPDF doesn't seem to support extracting content from existing PDFs.

Comment: from what i know it`s the the closest thing you can get...try usind docx (there are libraries) and at download convert to pdf, cheat it :-)